# Add name identifier to an array in a JSON object with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am new to JSON and Ruby on Rails (ruby 1.9.3, rails 3.2.13) and I am trying to add an array name/identifier to a JSON object that contains an already defined array.

My ruby on rails code in a controller is:

```
metricTypes = MetricType.all
respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => metricTypes}
end
```

What gets spit out is:

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"foo"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"bar"
    }
]
```

but what I would like to get is:

```
{
    metrics: [
        {
             "id":1,
             "name":"foo"
        },
        {
              "id":2,
              "name":"bar"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I modify the JSON object to include the array name/identifier? I may need to include other arrays other than "metrics" in the same json object in the future, which is why I am trying to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
metric_types = MetricType.all
hash = {:metrics => metrics_types}
```

then go

```
format.json {render :json => hash}
```

You may be interested in [Rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl)

Comment: @sko Good stuff, maybe tick the tick box to let anyone else who viewed this question know that it worked.